# Limit of two variables function by defintion

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove by definition that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(3,\pi)}x^{2}\sin(y)=0$$

Since
$$|f(x,y)-0|=|x^{2}|\cdot|\sin(y)|$$
and
$$|\sin(y)|\leq1$$
then
$$|f(x,y)-0|\leq|x^{2}|$$

Can I say that since
$$|x|\leq\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$
so
$$|x^{2}|=|x|^{2}\leq x^{2}+y^{2}$$
and therefore
$$|x|^{2}\leq(x-3)^{2}+(y-\pi)^{2}?$$

I'm not sure about the last inequality, but it's the only way I found to try to write $\delta$ using $\epsilon$.

**EDIT**

I tried to change the variables:
$$x=\bar{x}+3,\quad y=\bar{y}+\pi$$
so, I have the limit
$$\lim_{(\bar{x},\bar{y})\to(0,0)}(\bar{x}+3)^{2}\sin(\bar{y}+\pi)$$
and, still
$$|f(\bar{x},\bar{y})-0|\leq|(\bar{x}+3)^2|$$
but now I must to find $\delta$ such that
$$||(\bar{x},\bar{y})-(0,0)||<\delta$$
implies on
$$|f(\bar{x},\bar{y})-0|<\epsilon$$
Since
$$||(\bar{x},\bar{y})-(0,0)||=\sqrt{\bar{x}^{2}+\bar{y}^{2}}$$
then
$$\sqrt{\bar{x}^{2}+\bar{y}^{2}}<\delta\Rightarrow \bar{x}^{2}+\bar{y}^{2}<\delta^{2}$$
and, therefore
$$|\bar{x}|^{2}=\bar{x}^{2}\leq \bar{x}^{2}+\bar{y}^{2}<\delta^{2}\Rightarrow |\bar{x}|^{2}<\delta^{2}$$
and so
$$|\bar{x}|<\delta$$
Hence,
$$|(\bar{x}+3)^{2}|=|\bar{x}^{2}+6\bar{x}+9|\leq|\bar{x}^{2}|+6|\bar{x}|+9<\delta^{2}+6\delta+9=(\delta+3)^{2}$$
Then, if I take
$$\epsilon=(\delta+3)^{2}$$
the limit is proved.

I want to know if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked about the following limit: $\ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(3,\pi)}f(x,y)$

- we have $x\to 3$ and $y\to \pi$ so we want to compare $f(x,y)$ to $f(3,\pi)=9\sin(\pi)=0$

Our mathematical toolbox works better with limits in $0$ or $\infty$ so when we have a limit in "random" points, we often shift the function to study it around $0$.

- let set $\begin{cases}x=3+u &&u\to 0\\y=\pi+v&&v\to 0\end{cases}$

Notice $(u,v)\to(0,0)\implies (x,y)\to(3,\pi)$

You were on the right track but I feel that using $\bar x,\bar y$ just add some more confusion (also it is heavy to write), prefer the use of $(u,v)$ or $(h,k)$ or whatever seems familiar to you, using always the same letters will trigger math reflexes.

- we now have to study $\bigg|f(x,y)-f(3,\pi)\bigg|=\bigg|(3+u)^2\sin(\pi+v)-0\bigg|=\bigg|(3+u)^2\sin(v)\bigg|$

Since $\sin(\pi+v)=-\sin(v)$

Now you recognize $\sin(v)\to 0$ when $v\to 0$, for that we can use the inequality $|\sin(v)|\le |v|$

On the other hand $(3+u)^2$ does not really interests us, let just say $u\to 0$ so it is small, without loss of generality we can assume $|u|<1$ and then $(3+u)^2<16$

Note: *look at the end the choice of delta, $|u|<1$ is just convenient and not a limitation.*

- finally we arrived to $\bigg|f(x,y)-f(3,\pi)\bigg|\le 16|v|\to 0$

Now regarding the epsilon-delta definition of the limit, remember that norms in $\mathbb R^2$ are equivalent.

In particular using one of the $3$ standard ones $\begin{cases}\lVert(u,v)\lVert_1=|u|+|v|\\\\\lVert (u,v)\lVert_2=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\\\\\lVert(u,v)\lVert_\infty=\max(|u|,|v|)\\\end{cases}$ is up to you.

Select the one which is more convenient for the problem at hand

- since $\begin{cases}|u|\le |u|+|v|&&|u|\le\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\\|v|\le|u|+|v|&&|v|\le\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\end{cases}\implies \lVert(u,v)\lVert_\infty\le\lVert(u,v)\lVert_1\le2\lVert(u,v)\lVert_2$

- also $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\le\sqrt{u^2}+\sqrt{v^2}=|u|+|v|\implies \lVert(u,v)\lVert_2\le\lVert(u,v)\lVert_1\le2\lVert(u,v)\lVert_\infty$

In our case since we have to bound $|u|$ and $|v|$ then select $$\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{16})\text{ and }\lVert(u,v)\lVert_\infty<\delta$$

We have our result since $\begin{cases}|u|\le\max(|u|,|v|)<\delta\le 1\\|v|\le\max(|u|,|v|)<\delta\le \frac{\epsilon}{16}\end{cases}$

Notice that we do not have to do particularly confusing operations with $x-3$ and $y-\pi$ and square roots. The fact that we used $u,v$ and norm equivalence leads to a natural solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

We want:

$|x^2\sin(y)-0|<\epsilon$

We know that

$|x^2\sin(y)-0|$

$=|x^2\sin(y)|$

$= |x^2||\sin(y)|$

$= |(x-3+3)^2||\sin(y-\pi+\pi)|$

$ = |(x-3)+3|^2|\sin(y-\pi+\pi)|$

$ \le (|x-3|+|3|)^2|\sin((y-\pi)+\pi)|$

$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)$

so

$ = (|x-3|+3)^2|\sin(y-\pi)|$

So here I use that $|sin(a)|\le|a|$

$ \le (|x-3|+3)^2|y-\pi|$

We force $|x-3|<1$.

So then

$ (|x-3|+3)^2|y-\pi|$

$ < (1+3)^2|y-\pi|$

$ = 16|y-\pi|$

We want $16|y-\pi|$ to be $< \epsilon$

ie: we want $|y-\pi| < \frac{\epsilon}{16}$

Now we can do our proof.

Give an $\epsilon>0$ we choose $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{16}\}$

We've already shown that

$|x^2\sin(y)-0|$

$\le (|x-3|+3)^2|y-\pi|$

Now since $|x-3|<\delta$ and $|y-\pi|<\delta$

$(|x-3|+3)^2|y-\pi|$

$< (\delta+3)^2\delta$

$\le (1+3)^2\delta$

$\le 16\delta$

$\le 16(\frac{\epsilon}{16})$

$= \epsilon$

Comment: Why can I force $|x-3|<1$?

Comment: We can make sure $|x-3|<1$, by picking a delta that is less than or equal to 1. If we pick a delta less than or equal to 1, we know that $|x-3|<\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-\pi)^2}<\delta$. By bounding $|x-3|$ it simplifies the problem. We only need to make sure that when we pick our delta during the 'proper' proof we guarantee it is less than or equal to 1. That's why I chose $\delta =$ min{1, etc...

Comment: I chose 1 just for convenience. I could have chosen any number for the bound. Depending on the number the $\frac{\epsilon}{16}$ would change appropriately. But we'd get another valid solution.