# bounds between $l_1$ and $l_2$

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

It is known that in finite-dimensional spaces $l_1, l_2$ and $l_\infty$ norms are equivalent. That is, there exists constants $C_1,C_2 > 0$ such that
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ C_1||x||_1 \le ||x||_2 \le C_2||x||_{1}.$$
In what sources can I find the values of constants for these norms?

Comment: The first sentence is not accurate. In finite dimensions, all norms are equivalent, whether in infinite dimensions, the three norms are actually not equivalent.

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))?

Comment: I did it for two variables here, can you adapt to $n$ ? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3916803/399263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one source.

First, it is easy to show that $\|x\|_2\leq\|x\|_1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Next, by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\leq \sqrt{n}(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2)^{1/2}$$
so $$\|x\|_1\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_2\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R}^n)$$
So in your notation we get $C_1=n^{-1/2}$ and $C_2=1$. The constant $n^{-1/2}$ cannot be made larger, because if we choose $x_0$ to have all coordinates equal to $1$, then we have
$$\sqrt{n}=\|x_0\|_2=n^{-1/2}\cdot n=n^{-1/2}\|x_0\|_1$$

Similar arguments show that

$$\|x\|_{\infty}\leq\|x\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty},\qquad (x\in\mathbb{R}^n)$$
and we cannot replace $\sqrt{n}$ by a smaller constant.

Comment: @OP observe though that for equivalence $C_1=\sqrt{n}$ does not need to be the smallest possible, $C_1=n$ works fine too out of the simple inequality $|x_i|\le \lVert x\lVert_2,\ \forall i$.